Leaflet does not work with a specific basemap layer in R
I am recently working on a project. Its one dimension is to make a leaflet map with different basemap layers. Here is the code so far;
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", group = "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap", group = "Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap", group = "Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap",
                                  "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", "Esri.WorldStreetMap", 
                                  "Esri.WorldTopoMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"),
                   position = "topleft") 


this line of code provides me a working leaflet map. However when I add a different layer, namely TopPlusOpen.Color as suggested in this website: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/, the map does not show different layers it was showing previously and especially layers control on the top left side disappears. Here is the code for this error;
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("TopPlusOpen.Color", group = "TopPlusOpen.Color") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", group = "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap", group = "Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap", group = "Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap","TopPlusOpen.Color",
                                  "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", "Esri.WorldStreetMap", 
                                  "Esri.WorldTopoMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"),
                   position = "topleft") 

I could not understand what causes this problem, as  "TopPlusOpen.Color" is one of layers option and I look forward whether there are any similar layers to it that I can use. I appreciate any comments and suggestions and thank you beforehand.

It doesn't look like TopPlusOpen.Color is one of the default providers included in the providers list of the leaflet package. That said, you can still use those tiles using the URL template provided at the website in your original question. Instead of using addProviderTiles(), which fetches tiles from a pre-determined list of providers, you can add your own with addTiles() and supplying the urlTemplate argument (don't forget to attribute them properly!).
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_topplus_open/tile/1.0.0/web/default/WEBMERCATOR/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',
           attribution = 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.govdata.de/dl-de/by-2-0">dl-de/by-2-0</a>',
           group = "TopPlusOpen.Color") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.NatGeoWorldMap", group = "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap", group = "Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap", group = "Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c(
      "OpenStreetMap",
      "TopPlusOpen.Color",
      "Esri.NatGeoWorldMap",
      "Esri.WorldStreetMap",
      "Esri.WorldTopoMap",
      "Esri.WorldImagery"
    ),
    position = "topleft"
  )

The end result, with the TopPlusOpen.Color basemap tiles active, looks like the following:


Thank you so much as it was definitely something I was looking for. I see that, it was possible, using info on the website I have mentioned above. In that regard, may I kindly ask further whether it is possible to further customize these layers such as the language of places and etc. as described: https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/maps/basemap-layers/#basemap-styles-service. Additionally, is there a way to include different maps from different sources such as "Modern Antique Map" layers from the ArcGis website I have just gave its link.

Yes, but the link you reference refers to ArcGIS's Basemap Styles Service, which requires an ArcGIS Platform or ArcGIS Online account and an API key to use. So I imagine you could pass https://basemaps-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf to your urlTemplate template parameter, but you'd also need to pass the API key. I can't test this since I don't have one. Per the documentation, the language parameter can be set to any language code.
